# Difference between “on time” and “just in time”

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do the following sentences have the same meaning? or Is it slightly different?

> I arrived **just in time**, but no one else was there.
>
> I arrived **on time**, but no one else was there.
>
> I arrived **right on time**, but no one else was there.

Note: I couldn't figure out the answer from these questions:

- [“In time” versus “on time”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/in-time-versus-on-time)
- [Difference between "in time" and "on time"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9623/difference-between-in-time-and-on-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Be somewhere "on time", "at that time" or "in time"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128264/be-somewhere-on-time-at-that-time-or-in-time)

Answer (score 1):

```
I arrived just in time, but no one else was there.
```

This feels the start time of the event was significant, and that you were almost late. Something like the start of a race, or a bus leaving.

```
I arrived on time, but no one else was there.
```

I wasn't late.

```
I arrived right on time, but no one else was there.
```

I arrived exactly at the agreed time.