# 'in time' or 'on time'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context, phrase-choice

Is it 'in time' or 'on time' here?:

> ...
>
> GERRARD: Hello. Yes, speaking. Sorry I can’t let you have the props in
> time for rehearsal...

It's from a story in which *Gerrard* talks over the phone to someone and says a specific time duration, which I infer from this:

> GERRARD: ... Well, tell him to phone up directly. I must know ... Yes,
> I expect I’ll still be here, but you mustn’t count on that ... In
> about ten minutes’ time. Right-ho. Goodbye.

[This](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/iebe111.pdf) is the story where the line is.

From [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/9626/140246), can I say that the "in time" here is correct too, or is 'on time' the correct phrase to be used in the sentence? My point is that, since a specific time is mentioned, from *so-to-so*, 'in time' should be correct. Or, should it be something like "in this time" or "in the time" where 'this' and 'the' refer to the time *interval*?

If I'm not wrong, 'on time' is usually used when the task is completed at the brink of the moment. As the meaning is decided by the author, I only say that it either would be either 'in time' or 'in <pronoun/word referring to the time interval> time' as when such a phrase is used, it usually means/refers to "between (time1 and time2)"/"in the time of (time2-time1)", time1 and time2 (in this case, the then-current time and that + 10 minutes) being mentioned *earlier*, and its meaning is/can be *totally* different from *on time*'s.

I know that there are many grammatical errors in the sentences, but the question is the title.

Please correct me if I'm wrong; I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If something happens ***'on time'*** that means it happened *at the time when it was scheduled to happen* (it's very strongly implied that there ***is*** a specific pre-planned time for it to happen). But something can happen ***'in time'*** even if there was no specific scheduled time involved - that just means it *didn't happen **too late*** (for something else to also happen, be prevented from happening, or whatever). But that ***in/on time*** distinction is irrelevant to expressions like ***in ten minutes time*** (ten minutes from now), which ***never*** involve preposition ***on***.

Comment: Yes, 'in time' is not too late; 'on time' is punctual.

Comment: So... are you asking about the difference between *We arrived **on/in** time for the concert*, or *We will leave **in** five minutes time*?

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking which would fit there and the difference in this context.

Comment: Gerrard cannot let the caller have the stage props **in time** for the rehearsal, that is, by the time it is scheduled to begin.

Comment: @KateBunting, oh, thanks. So, 'in time' is used correctly, right? Can 'on time' be used, and which is the more common phrase used in this type of context?

Comment: See Michael's comment above. The train was _on time_ - we arrived at the station _in time_ to catch it.

Comment: @KateBunting, oh. So, is it?

Comment: Do you mean "Is _in time_ used correctly in the quotation?" Yes - I told you in my earlier comment what it means. The props could only be delivered at a time that was too late for the rehearsal.

Comment: @KateBunting, yes, I do. Thanks! Would the meaning of 'on time' be the same in this case (instead of "in time") too? Or, as FumbleFingers says, *"But that in/on time distinction is irrelevant to expressions like in ten minutes time (ten minutes from now), which never involve preposition on"*, will using 'on time' instead be wrong (because it would refer to the time *interval* and not a time *instance* and as then, "on time1 to time2" would be wrong)?

Comment: As far as I know (and as we have all tried to explain), 'on time' _only_ means 'punctually, at the appointed time'.